# CookieAuthenticationOptions Events not firing on TestServer

Tags: authentication, cookies, asp.net-identity, integration-testing, identityserver4

I have an Integration test using using Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost. On my startup I have added the `CookieAuthentication(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies)` middleware

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationScheme = "Cookies",
    AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
    AutomaticChallenge = true,
    Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents()
    {
        OnValidatePrincipal = CookieAuthenticationOnValidatePrincipal    
    }
});
```

In test, I can successfully login and get the access_token. I have an action with `[Authorize]` attribute when i try to access that `OnValidatePrincipal` event does not fire, but if i change the AuthenticationScheme to a different middleware, the authentication failed at the first place. My question is why any events are not firing for `AuthenticationScheme = "Cookies"`? I guess i am missing something